# Check Android app for ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency

How do I write a test that continually closes and opens an Android app until there is a runtimeexception (showing the stack Trace)? I need this to repro a rare concurrency problem which occurs on start up of our app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it:

```
for i in {1..100}; do adb -d shell am force-stop XXX && adb shell am start -n XXX/.YYY && sleep 10s; done
```

where you need to replace XXX with the `applicationId` from your `build.gradle` and YYY with you default activity from your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

And from an other terminal, run:

```
adb -d logcat ZZZ:E *:S
```

where ZZZ is your app's name. This will show you a stack trace similar to

```
E/ZZZ(19737): Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
E/ZZZ(19737):   at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
```